# isc-dhcp-server.serviceの遅延起動

Tags: raspberry-pi, systemd

## 環境

model:RaspberryPi4 B
OS:raspberry pi OS
DHCPサーバー:isc-dhcp-server

## やりたいこと

eht0を固定IPかつDHCPサーバーとして、固有のネットワークに同一サブネットのIPアドレスを割り当てる。

## 問題点

本体起動時にisc-dhcp-serverが自動起動するのですが、eth0ポートの稼働より前に起動してしまい、eth0にサブネットが割り当てられていない旨のエラーが発生しています。

エラーの確認方法
1.サービス一覧の状況確認

```bash
systemctrl list-units --type=service
```

ここで、エラーが発生していることが分かる。
2.具体的な内容の確認

```bash
journalctl -u isc-dhcp-server.service
```

## 遅延起動の必要性

一旦、isc-dhcp-server.serviceを停止させる。

```bash
systemctl stop isc-dhcp-server.service
```

```bash
systemctl start isc-dhcp-server.service
```

サービス再起動すると正常に起動します。

## 解決したいこと

isc-dhcp-server.serviceの遅延起動方法
できれば、eth0の監視を行って起動する方法

Answer (score 1):

systemdはそれほど詳しくはありませんが。

[systemdで確実にネットワークの起動後にサービスを起動させたい場合のメモ](https://kernhack.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/09/20/110938)

```
[Unit]
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Do something

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

というようにサービスファイルを書けばいいらしいです。
もしくは、もしあれば既にインストールされている他のネットワークサービス(apache、sshなど)のサービスファイルを参考にされてはいかがですか。

ところでちょっと気になりましたが、aptでインストールすればこの辺りの設定はいい感じにやってくれると思うのですが、そうされていないのですか？